# Controls on the Windows Form are cropping from bottom

Tags: c#, winforms, panels

I have a windows form which contains five panels, who's total height is greater than computer screen's total resolution (height), therefore the controls in the bottom ( which are inside  the panel and  who's doc property is set to  bottom) are cropping from bottom. How could I avoid this?

I have attached the image for visualizing the issue.

[image]

Comment: Try to use `FlowLayoutPanel` into form as the parent control of all your panels.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sure I will try @X-TECH

Comment: Didn't you set AutoScroll = true?

Comment: Yes, dear @TaW I have set the AutoScroll = true.

Comment: That is strange; setting the Form's  AutoScroll property should be all that's needed to make scrollbars appear when necessary..Or do you mean the __panel crops its__ content??  Then you could set its Autoscroll or its Autosize, depending what you want, probably the latter

Comment: This is quite broad, there are many options. You could also break the *groups* into tabs  or use multiple *columns* where the checkboxes are etc.

Comment: I prefer to reorder controls and remove spaces (for example in settings part) or also yo can make your last pannel smaller in heght. Also TaW's `AutoScroll` offer is good offer.

Comment: @ImranKhanHunzai You have set autoscroll of form true, but probably you have a panel with Dock = Fill that hosts your controls. Set AutoScrollProperty of your panel to true instead of form

Comment: Ok I should apply your suggestions. @TaW

Comment: This is good idea, I should use tabs @Lloyd

Comment: Yes, there is a main panel which is holding all these panels. Sure I will try your option. I will apply AutoScroll on main panel @RezaAghaei

Comment: Thanks for your kind help @TaW